# can I program a nano over SPI with another nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, spi

I'm fairly new to arduino, but I want to program a nano over SPI to skip the bootloader. I know I can program the nano with an uno as a programmer to do this, but I don't have an uno, but I do have a couple of nanos. Can I set up one as a programmer, connect it to another over SPI, and program the 2nd?

Comment: from software side there is no difference between Uno and Nano 2018 with new bootloader. older Nano can have old bootloader. Wire over ICSP headers one to one except of the reset pin which should be wired to pin 10 on programmer board

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. They use ATmega328 / Atmega328P microcontrollers, which are basically the same.

(The differencies of those microcontrollers are about Brown Out Detection - how they could be set to react on too low voltage. No problem in nearly any Arduino operation.)

The boards differ mainly in the board size and places for pins.

Comment: Nano has 328p too. Arduino doesn't use ATmega328

Comment: The better then - I do not have one at hands now, so I cannot check it physically. I found the Atmega328 (without P) was mentioned in Tech Specs here https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano so I kinda trusted them, but they may did typo or had more verssions historically. Anyway even if they would differ, it would work, if they are both the same, it would work too :)